# Cannot find module 'AsyncStorage' when testing with Jest/Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm doing simple tests in react-native with Jest and Enzyme. At the moment I am testing and mocking the AsyncStorage, but every test where I do this, it fails. I tried putting the code inside a `beforeEach(() => {})`, but it doesn't work either. Check the code below:

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import MockStorage from '../../__mocks__/mockStorage';

const middlewares = [thunk]; 
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

describe('testing AsyncStorage', () => {

    // Mock AsyncStorage
    const storageCache = {
        '@token': '123sometoken987',
        '@messages': 'this is a message'
    };

    const AsyncStorage = new MockStorage(storageCache);
    jest.setMock('AsyncStorage', AsyncStorage);
            ^ // fails here

    // ...
})
```

Here is my `mockStorage.js`:

```
export default class MockStorage {
    constructor(cache = {}) {
      this.storageCache = cache;
    }

    setItem = jest.fn((key, value) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return (typeof key !== 'string' || typeof value !== 'string')
            ? reject(new Error('key and value must be string'))
            : resolve(this.storageCache[key] = value);
         });
    });

    getItem = jest.fn((key) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        return this.storageCache.hasOwnProperty(key)
            ? resolve(this.storageCache[key])
            : resolve(null);
        });
    });

    removeItem = jest.fn((key) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return this.storageCache.hasOwnProperty(key)
            ? resolve(delete this.storageCache[key])
            : reject('No such key!');
        });
    });

    clear = jest.fn((key) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  resolve(this.storageCache = {}));
    });

    getAllKeys = jest.fn((key) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(Object.keys(this.storageCache)));
    });
  }
```

The test fails with the following error:

> Cannot find module 'AsyncStorage' from 'myFileName.js'

Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that worked for me for those who are still looking. Mocking the entire react-native module didn't work, but providing the path to the AsyncStorage module did.

```
const mockItems = {};
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Storage/AsyncStorage', () => ({
    setItem: jest.fn((item, value) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            mockItems[item] = value;
            resolve(value);
        });
    }),
    getItem: jest.fn((item) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(mockItems[item]);
        });
    }),
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! Just spent a whole day digging, and this finally solved the problem. This is useful for anyone using AsyncStorage on React Native with Expo (which doesn't support the new @react-native-community/AsyncStorage yet)

Answer (score -1):

You may try to set mock in a `beforeEach` in your test file instead of your `setMock` at root level

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  const storageCache = {
    '@token': '123sometoken987',
    '@messages': 'this is a message'
  };

  jest.mock('AsyncStorage', () => new MockStorage(storageCache));
});
```

Comment: I get like a huge error: `babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The module factory of "jest.mock()" is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
    Invalid variable access: storageCache`@colinux

Comment: Try by moving `storageCache` object directly inside `new MockStorage`: `new MockStorage({ '@token': "..." })`

Comment: It's throwing the same error `Cannot find module "AsyncStorage"...`. Btw, there is a `)` missing in your answer. @colinux

Comment: How are you importing `AsyncStorage` in your tested file ?

Comment: `import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'`, but the import is not being used with my code or yours. On my question is how I am implementing. @colinux